# Is ODE theory useful for developing numerical solvers for ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, research

I will be doing research in developing numerical solvers for ODEs. I was wondering if knowledge of ODE theory will be useful and if so in what ways.

I am asking because, I am inclined to take a class (I'm in grad school) in ODE theory. But more experienced members in my lab are advising against saying it will not be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on the applied mathematics or engineering side of the fence?

Comment: I am doing PhD in Computational Science.

Comment: classical stuffs focused on analytic skills so I guess is not useful to you. But modern geometric approach is definitely important and useful. Besides, what would be the point of your ODE solver if there is no theoretical novelty in it?

Comment: If you are doing PhD in Computational Science, you may be interested in SE site called [scicomp.se]... where this question would likely get more action.

Comment: @Thursday thanks! I will definitely check it out.